# Firefox bfcache issue?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, firefox, browser-cache

I am having trouble with only firefox. My page shows a tree structure that is loaded via ajax as the user clicks on the nodes they want to expand. The problem I'm having with firefox, and only firefox, is that it will expand the nodes on the first page load. But after that firefox caches it weird and the node header, not children, of the ajax request gets carried over to the new page. This is an issue because the node's header that is carried over contains information that determines if the node has retrieved it's children.

```
<div class="node topbar"
   <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="hasretrievedchildren" value="1"/>
...
</div>
```

It should be as it is on the first page load.

```
<div class="node topbar"
   <input type="hidden" id="foo" name="hasretrievedchildren" value="0"/>
...
</div>
```

My Javascript checks for a nonzero value on that input to do the AJAX call.

Is this a bfcache issue? 
I'm lead to believe it's not because I added

```
window.onunload = function();
```

to the js file and in a script tag and neither fixed it which this article
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching
says should invalidate the bfcache.

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 and I tried using the MVCdonutcaching to set this page and partial views to not cache. But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. Firefox caches all form data even hidden inputs. Since I was using a hidden field to store the flag that enabled the AJAX request it would reload the form data with the flag set. I moved it to a custom attribute and it works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the bfcache, maybe it's not.
I had to face the same problem some time ago. The browser caches were causing some strange behaviour on our forms, and it was affecting the expected results of the page.
Someway to solve itSomething you can do in order to make the program load always the correct value (assuming you are loading it from ) is to initialize the value through your Javascript.

If you use JQuery, you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(){
      //Assign your items values here
    }
<script>
```

You can also use the onload handler in JS.

Hope this helps.